# Differentiating this problem $\frac{2t^{3/2}}{\ln(2t^{3/2}+1)}$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

How does one differentiate the function
$$y(t)=\frac{2t^{3/2}}{\ln(2t^{3/2}+1)}.$$

I am still tying to understand MathJaX and not sure what is wrong with the expression.
Anyways,

How do I start/process solving this? Do i take the ln of both side? If so I get the log of the top - the log of the bottom. which is the log of a log? If I do the quotient rule right away, i get the log expression in the bottom squared. Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the quotient rule is probably the best option. The symmetry of the $2 t^{2/3}$ in the top and bottom makes me suspect that some things might end up canceling out.

Comment: Is there anyway to simplify the denominator i get then

$(ln(2t^{3/2}+1))^2$

Edit* actually this only thing turns out very ugly

Comment: $$y(t)=\frac{3t^{1/2}ln(2t^{3/2}+1) - \frac{6t^2}{2t^{3/2}+1}}{\ln(2t^{3/2}+1)}$$

This is what I get, but Idk how to write it correctly using MathJax. I tried :/ this is so ugly i dont even know how to simplify it

Comment: You're missing a bracket before the first 1/2

Comment: And how did you get $6t^2$?

Comment: $2t^{3/2} * 3t^{1/2}$

Comment: Sorry I was having trouble reading without it formatted. I see. If you care about making it look nice don't multiply that out and factor out a $3t^{1/2}$. Then you could try getting common denominators with the $2t^{3/2}+1$.

Comment: That's really all I can offer. The rest is just simplification and is a matter of teacher or personal preference

Comment: THats what Ill do then. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Getting the square of the logarithm in the denominator is a fact.  You have tools for differentiating, so apply them
$$y(t)=\frac{2t^{3/2}}{\ln(2t^{3/2}+1)}\\
y'(t)=\frac{3t^{1/2}\ln(2t^{3/2}+1)-2t^{3/2}\frac1{2t^{3/2}+1}3t^{1/2}}{((\ln(2t^{3/2}+1))^2}$$ which you can simplify if you want by distributing out the $3t^{1/2}$, but that is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'm pretty sure this answer will be satisfactory. Usually, you aren't asked to simplify more than this.

Comment: This doesn't use the quotient rule, just the plain natural log trick...

Comment: @Connor You don't need to use the quotient rule; the answer is obtained quicker this way!